# How to pass the Confirmation box clicked 'Yes' to a separate view model? How to show dialog the MVVM way?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Currently I'm developing a WPF application using MVVM pattern, So I got into a problem where I have a Confirmation Message Box, there if User clicked 'Yes' I need to a certain operation , If User clicked 'No' no need to do anything.

So the implementation related to operation is in a separate view model in the application, So I got into a problem where i couldn't pass the status(if user clicked 'Yes' status is true) to the view model. Can someone please advice me a good approach for this? Any advice or guidance will be highly appreciated,since I'm new to WPF.

Comment: IMHO utilize some kind of messenger/mediator that would allows a message to be sent and then you can act on that message.

Comment: I agree with the above. A messenger is probably the easiest way to do this. MVVM Light Messenger is one option.

Comment: @RyanThomas suggestion is great, MVVM Light will have you going in no time. On the other hand, [Josh Smith](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/a-mediator-prototype-for-wpf-apps/) has a nice article about this you could check out if you don't want to pull in MVVM Light.

Comment: When Clicked 'Yes' Event is get fired, So I already Used a Mediator inside the Event,But when it returns to the particular View model, that property which sets by mediator, becomes 'null'. Can anyone guide me with this? What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a working example. It shows the recommended way to display a dialog from the view model without violating the MVVM pattern by using an attached behavior. It is very flexible in terms of customization as it makes use of `DataTemplate` to design the content of a dialog which is an instance of `Window`.

Setting the `DialogViewModel` property of the `ViewModel` (see example) will trigger the display of the dialog. An implicit `DataTemplate` (recommended to be defined in the global `ResourceDictionary` of the *App.xaml* file) will define the content of the dialog. Each `DataTemplate` must target an implementation of `DialogViewModel` (`DataTemplate.DataType`).
This approach is also known as View Model First.

Inside the `DataTemplate` for the dialog simply bind each `Button` to the `DialogViewModel.SendResponseCommand` and use the `DialogResult` `enum` as `CommandParameter`. Once the dialog was closed the `DialogViewModel.SendResponseCommand` asynchronously invokes a registered callback. This way the whole behavior is `async` and fire-and-forget.

**Dialog.cs**
Attached Behavior that handles showing and closing of the dialog. When closed it invokes an asynchronous callback to complete the interaction with the dialog.

```
public class Dialog : DependencyObject
{
  #region DialogDataContext attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogDataContextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "DialogDataContext", typeof(DialogViewModel), typeof(Dialog), new PropertyMetadata(default(DialogViewModel), Dialog.OnDialogDataContextChanged));

  public static void SetDialogDataContext(DependencyObject attachingElement, DialogViewModel value) => attachingElement.SetValue(Dialog.DialogDataContextProperty, value);

  public static DialogViewModel GetDialogDataContext(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (DialogViewModel)attachingElement.GetValue(Dialog.DialogDataContextProperty);

  #endregion

  private static Dictionary<DialogViewModel, Window> ViewModelToDialogMap { get; }

  static Dialog()
  {
    Dialog.ViewModelToDialogMap = new Dictionary<DialogViewModel, Window>();
  }

  public static bool TryGetDialog(DialogViewModel viewModel, out Window dialog) => Dialog.ViewModelToDialogMap.TryGetValue(viewModel, out dialog);

  private static void OnDialogDataContextChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.NewValue is DialogViewModel newDialogViewModel && attachingElement is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
      if (frameworkElement.IsLoaded)
      {
        Dialog.Show(attachingElement, newDialogViewModel);
      }
      else
      {
        frameworkElement.Loaded += Dialog.ShowDialogOnAttachingElementLoaded;
      }
    }
  }

  private static void ShowDialogOnAttachingElementLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (sender is Window window
        && window.DataContext is DialogViewModel dialogViewModel)
    {
      window.ContentTemplate = window.TryFindResource(dialogViewModel.GetType()) as DataTemplate;
    }
  }

  private static void Show(DependencyObject attachingElement, DialogViewModel newDialogViewModel)
  {
    newDialogViewModel.InteractionCompleted += Dialog.CloseDialogOnInteractionCompleted;
    Window window = Dialog.Prepare(attachingElement, newDialogViewModel);
    window.Closed += Dialog.CleanUpOnDialogClosed;
    Dialog.ViewModelToDialogMap.Add(newDialogViewModel, window);
    window.Show();
  }

  private static Window Prepare(DependencyObject attachingElement, DialogViewModel newDialogViewModel)
  {
    var window = new Window
    {
      Icon = newDialogViewModel.TitleBarIcon,
      SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
      WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner,
      Topmost = true,
      Title = newDialogViewModel.Title,
      DataContext = newDialogViewModel,
      Content = newDialogViewModel,
      ContentTemplateSelector = Dialog.GetDataTemplateSelector(attachingElement),
      Style = Dialog.GetStyle(attachingElement)
    };

    if (attachingElement is Window parentWindow
        || Dialog.TryFindVisualParentElement(attachingElement, out parentWindow))
    {
      window.Owner = parentWindow;
    }
    return window;
  }

  private static bool TryFindVisualParentElement<TParent>(DependencyObject child, out TParent resultElement)
    where TParent : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    DependencyObject parentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    if (parentElement is TParent parent)
    {
      resultElement = parent;
      return true;
    }

    return Dialog.TryFindVisualParentElement(parentElement, out resultElement);
  }

  private static void CleanUpOnDialogClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var dialogViewModel = (sender as Window).DataContext as DialogViewModel;
    Dialog.ViewModelToDialogMap.Remove(dialogViewModel);
    dialogViewModel.InteractionCompleted -= Dialog.CloseDialogOnInteractionCompleted;
  }

  private static void CloseDialogOnInteractionCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (Dialog.ViewModelToDialogMap.TryGetValue(sender as DialogViewModel, out Window dialog))
    {
      dialog.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

**DialogViewModel.cs**
The abstract dialog view model base class. Each dialog type (appearance) needs to implement a dedicated `DialogViewModel` to show the individual dialog.

```
public abstract class DialogViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  protected DialogViewModel(string message, string title) : this(message, title, (dialogViewModel) => Task.CompletedTask)
  {
  }
  protected DialogViewModel(string message, string title, Func<DialogViewModel, Task> sendResponseCallbackAsync) : this(message, title, null, sendResponseCallbackAsync)
  {
  }

  protected DialogViewModel(string message, string title, ImageSource titleBarIcon, Func<DialogViewModel, Task> sendResponseCallbackAsync)
  {
    this.ResponseCallbackAsync = sendResponseCallbackAsync;
    this.Message = message;
    this.Title = title;
    this.TitleBarIcon = titleBarIcon;
  }

  protected virtual async void ExecuteResponseCallback(object result)
  {
    this.DialogResult = (DialogResult) result;
    await this.ResponseCallbackAsync.Invoke(this).ConfigureAwait(false);
    OnInteractionCompleted();
  }

  private string title;   
  public string Title
  {
    get => this.title;
    set 
    { 
      this.title = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }


  private string message;   
  public string Message
  {
    get => this.message;
    set 
    { 
      this.message = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private ImageSource titleBarIcon;
  public ImageSource TitleBarIcon
  {
    get => this.titleBarIcon;
    set
    {
      this.titleBarIcon = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public RelayCommand SendResponseCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteResponseCallback, (param) => true);

  private DialogResult dialogResult;   
  public DialogResult DialogResult
  {
    get => this.dialogResult;
    set 
    { 
      this.dialogResult = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private Func<DialogViewModel, Task> responseCallbackAsync;   
  public Func<DialogViewModel, Task> ResponseCallbackAsync
  {
    get => this.responseCallbackAsync;
    set 
    { 
      this.responseCallbackAsync = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event EventHandler InteractionCompleted;
  protected virtual void OnInteractionCompleted()
  {
    this.InteractionCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**FileExistsDialogViewModel.cs**
Example implementation of abstract `DialogViewModel`. You can replace it with your custom implementatio or rename the class. But don't forget to adjust the `DataTemplate.DataType` to match the this type.

```
public class FileExistsDialogViewModel : DialogViewModel
{
  public FileExistsDialogViewModel(string message, string title) : base(message, title)
  { 
  }
  public FileExistsDialogViewModel(string message, string title, Func<DialogViewModel, Task> sendResponseCallbackAsync) : base(message, title, sendResponseCallbackAsync)
  { 
  }
  public FileExistsDialogViewModel(string message, string title, ImageSource titleBarIcon, Func<DialogViewModel, Task> sendResponseCallbackAsync) : base(message, title, titleBarIcon, sendResponseCallbackAsync)
  { 
  }
}
```

**DialogResult.cs**

```
public enum DialogResult
{
  None = 0, Accepted, Denied, Aborted
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**
Implementation taken from [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic)

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
  #region Fields 
  readonly Action<object> _execute;
  readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
  #endregion // Fields 
  #region Constructors 
  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
  {
    if (execute == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
    }

    this._execute = execute; this._canExecute = canExecute;
  }
  #endregion // Constructors 
  #region ICommand Members 
  [DebuggerStepThrough]
  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return this._canExecute == null ? true : this._canExecute(parameter);
  }
  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
  }
  public void Execute(object parameter) { this._execute(parameter); }
  #endregion // ICommand Members 
}
```

**App.xaml** (`DataTemplate` for the dialog)

```
<Application x:Class="Main.App"
             Startup="RunApplication">
    <Application.Resources>
      <ViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel />

      <Viewbox x:Key="WarningIcon"
               x:Shared="False">
        <ContentControl FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                        Content="&#xE814;" />
      </Viewbox>
      <Viewbox x:Key="WarningLightIcon"
               x:Shared="False">
        <ContentControl FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                        Content="&#xE7BA;" />
      </Viewbox>

      <!-- 
        Implicit DataTemplate that applies to types of FileExistsDialogViewModel.
        You can replace or modify it. 
        Just wire every dialog Button.Command to the 
        DialogViewModel.SendResponseCommand (reference via DataContext of this DataTemplate)
        and pass in a DialogResult enum value to the Button.CommandParameter
      -->
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FileExistsDialogViewModel}">
        <Grid Margin="12">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                      Margin="0,0,48,24">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,16,0">
              <ContentControl Panel.ZIndex="1"
                              Content="{StaticResource WarningIcon}"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Height="32"
                              Foreground="Orange"
                              Background="Black" />
              <ContentControl Panel.ZIndex="2"
                              Content="{StaticResource WarningLightIcon}"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Height="32"
                              Margin="0,4,0,0" />
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
          </StackPanel>
          <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                      FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=CancelButton}"
                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Content="Yes"
                    Padding="0"
                    Command="{Binding SendResponseCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{x:Static DialogResult.Accepted}"
                    Margin="0,0,16,0" />
            <Button x:Name="CancelButton"
                    Content="No"
                    IsCancel="True"
                    IsDefault="True"
                    BorderThickness="3"
                    Padding="0"
                    Command="{Binding SendResponseCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{x:Static DialogResult.Denied}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

### Usage

**ViewModel.cs**
Sets the dialog view model for the requested dialog. Registers a continuation callback which is invoked after the dialog was closed.

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
  public void ShowFileAlreadyExistsDialog()
  {  
    // Initialize the DialogViewModel implementation for the File Exists dialog
    var dialogTitleBarIcon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../logo.ico", UriKind.Relative));
    if (titleBarIcon.CanFreeze)
    {
      titleBarIcon.Freeze();
    }

    var message = "File exists. Do you want to replace it?";
    var dialogTitle = "File Exists";

    // Set the continuation callback which will be invoked once the dialog closed
    DialogViewModel fileExistsdialogViewModel = new FileExistsDialogViewModel(
      message, 
      dialogTitle, 
      dialogTitleBarIcon, 
      dialogViewModel => HandleFileExistsDialogResponseAsync(dialogViewModel, filePath, settingsData));

    // Show the dialog by setting the DialogViewModel property to an instance of DialogViewModel
    this.DialogViewModel = fileExistsdialogViewModel;
  }

  // Continuation callback. Will be invoked once the dialog closed. 
  // The parameter is the previously created FileExistsDialogViewmodel containing data set from the dialog.
  private async Task HandleFileExistsDialogResponseAsync(DialogViewModel dialogViewModel, string filePath, string settingsData)
  {
    if (dialogViewModel.DialogResult == DialogResult.Accepted)
    {
      // Example method
      await SaveFileAsync(filePath, settingsData);
    }
  }

  private DialogViewModel dialogViewModel;   
  public DialogViewModel DialogViewModel
  {
    get => this.dialogViewModel;
    set 
    { 
      this.dialogViewModel = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**
Apply the attached property to `Window` or any other `FrameworkElement`.

```
<Window x:Class="BionicCode.BionicNuGetDeploy.Main.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        xmlns:dialog="clr-namespace:BionicUtilities.Net.Dialog;assembly=BionicUtilities.Net"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}
        Dialog.DialogDataContext="{Binding DialogViewModel}">
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for our kind support... Since I'm a beginner,this answer is little bit complex and hard to understand. and tried to run this code but it gives lot of errors.Can u briefly add the important code snippets only. @BionicCode

Comment: @sm1184 Sorry, I fixed some errors by removing class references to types I didn't show here (e.g., `IBaseViewModel` and `BaseViewModel`). I also replaced the more complex types `IAsyncRelayCommand<T>` and `AsyncRelayCommand<T>` with a `RelayCommand<T>` implementation taken from the internet, just to reduce the files and code. You should be able to copy&paste the code without errors. Otherwise please let me know. Better copy everything again.

Comment: @sm1184 If you are experiencing any difficulties just let me know.

Comment: Sill it gives me errors., What are these [NotNull] attribute ,and IDialogViewModel also asking to implement the interface , and what's this IDialogViewModelProvider it also making lot of errors in the code, Can u please help me with this?

Comment: Atta boy for the work (they won't let me say +1), but this is a large example...couldn't it be distilled to a smaller example? :-)

Comment: @sm1184 you can safely remove this attribute or reference jetbrains.annotation package via NuGet.  Just leave it. What kind of errors are you experiencing? Can't be a huge deal to fix them.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan sorry, it's part of my library and I extracted and pasted the relevant code. I already modified it to make it simpler by leaving away referenced classes. In general this should be a working code. But you are right. It's still a lot of code. Tomorrow I will reduce it to an absolute minimum of you are still interested. There are some features included that are not necessary just to show the dialog or to show the basic principle.

Comment: I'm good...I just hate to see a good chunk of work go to naught due to SO closing posts. thx Though I will l@@k into Jetbrains annotation package, to see if its relevant to anything I am working on.

Comment: @sm1184 @ΩmegaMan sorry, that's another remainder from the copy&paste action. I removed the `IDialogViewModelProvider` from the `MainWindowViewModel`. Thanks for your time and patience to make this code compile. The original code is taken from my library and is 110% working. I first thought passing the raw code would be sufficient and you would modify it to make it run. Sorry my bad. You can retry and we fix it together or you wait until tomorrow until I come home from work. Then I will fix it and post compiling and further reduced code by removing some features.

Comment: @sm1184 Not sure if you're still interested, but I fixed the whole code. Should compile now whithout any additional packages etc.

Answer (score 1):

> ... pass to a seperate ViewModel

How about the operation to be done is *instead* passed to the place that launches the dialog? I.E. Inject the operation to be done which can be executed at the reading of the dialog result?

To do that one can use [WPF Commanding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview) to achieve the desired result.

---

An untested example is this

**VM**

This VM is accessible to where the result of the dialog can be read (or passed in as a dependency property etc). On that VM create a placeholder for the operation.

```
ICommand DoMyYesOperation { get; set; }
```

Then on the other VM **subscribe** to that' other VM's property with an ICommand action. Or have the VM setup an action itself which contacts the other vm...etc. Such as:

```
    public ICommand DoMyYesOperation { get; set; } = new ActionCommand(
        () => {  //
                 // DoWhatEver It is
              }
        );
```

- Note that `ActionCommand` is available from the `using Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;` namespace. (Run your program through Blend to get it attached). Or build your own....

Then where you get the result, simply execute the action such as

```
 if (dialogResult = OK)
    (VM reference).DoMyYesOperation.Execute();
```

---

I give an example on my blog of commanding with a class which implements `ICommand` for another example

- [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)